# Schema.org - Ratings from different sources

Tags: google-search, schema.org

**Long question short**

On my website companies can be reviewed. Reviews from other sources (TrustPilot) are also allowed. What should I have my Schema.org markup say if there are 2 reviews on my website and 1000 on TrustPilot?

1. I make my Schema.org say there are 2 reviews only. User visits my website. Sees 1002 reviews. Is confused.
2. I make my Schema.org say there are 1002 reviews. User sees "about" card (not the search result) of company in Google. Says the company has 2002 reviews (1000 on TrustPilot, 1002 on my website). Information is incorrect.

**Long question long (more details)**

For a client that has a price comparison website I am asked to implement Schema.org markup. This website gives you - simply put - an overview of at which companies you can buy product X and for what price. On the client's website these companies can be reviewed. The client offers companies the option to show reviews from different sources (e.g. TrustPilot) as well. For example company A could be rated twice on the client's website and once on TrustPilot, giving an average rating of [total rating] / 3.

What of this data should I include in the Schema.org markup? Should I include ratings from sources different than the client's own website?

That could mean that for a company A - when Google reads the client's website's Schema.org markup for Company A - Google would say "hey, we see 8000 reviews on TrustPilot, and 8002 on [client's website] (8000 from TrustPilot, 2 from the client's website), that's a total of 16002 ratings". Or wouldn't Google?

On the other hand, if I make the Schema.org markup say that the rating is only [rating based on client website's ratings], then Google would create a rich snippet in its results saying the rating is x, then the user would end up on our website and see a different rating, consisting of ratings from all sources.

What to do here?

Comment: Is the (only) goal to get Google’s [Reviews rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews)? Or do you want to provide structured data for other reasons, too?

Comment: Just for Google. But I don't want to confuse people that find us through Google. If Google says "6 reviews with an avg. rating of 8.4", I don't want people to visit the website and see "806 reviews with an avg. of 8.2".